# Memory leak using axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, memory-leaks, axios

I'm just starting an app using reactjs and axios. It fetches some rather big JSON data and after a few minutes, Chromium stops writing "Paused before potential out-of-memory leak". It looks like all fetched data is stored somewhere, but I don't understand how. The code looks like

```
let result = axios({...});
result = result.then((response) => {
    ... read status and headers, pass them to other functions
    return response;
}, (error) => {
    ... never executed similar processing
    return response; // error processing done
});
if (method === "get") {
    result = result.then((response) => {
        ... some header processing
    }
}
return null; // currently, the result is no more needed
```

There's no single place, where the response data could leak... I don't need them yet, as I'm currently concerned with the fetching logic only. The promise doesn't not get out of the method not do `response` and `response.data`. But the 2 GB memory snapshot shows the fetched JSON data:

[image: leak]

This happens also in incognito mode, where no extensions are running. The most suspicious line is "Pending activities". I don't understanding a lot of things there, e.g., why it's listed below compiled code (it's just data, JSON with the non-executable prefix, and I've never touched it).

I started with create-react-app and installed the following

```
  "dependencies": {
    "axios": "^0.18.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.75.0",
    "json-stable-stringify": "^1.0.1",
    "react": "^16.4.1",
    "react-bootstrap": "^0.32.1",
    "react-burger-menu": "^2.5.2",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-scripts": "1.1.4",
    "react-select": "^1.2.1",
    "react-sidemenu": "0.0.14",
    "serve": "^9.1.0"
  },
```

The problem occurs also with the production build.

After writing it all, I found out that the problem does *not* occur when chrome DevTools are closed, so it's not really important. However, I've got an angularjs app fetching the same data and there's no such problem.

Does someone know what causes the leak and how I can get rid of it?

Comment: Could you post your code as it is in your script without modification? It's hard to understand what do you wanted to do with this edit.

Comment: [Doc](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/) could be very helpfull in situations like this because we cant debug whats wrong just by looking at basic info you provided..

Comment: any update on this issue?